# c++ - have a function output the information of a separate function to a textfile

Tags: c++

I want to output what one of my functions prints out into a separate textfile. I have tried what I have below but I get an error saying "invalid operands to binary expression" when I try outfile << print();. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void printing();

int main() {
  printing();
  printFile();
}

void printing() {
  cout << "Cheers";
}

void printFile() {
  ofstream cout("World.txt", ios::out);

  if (cout) {
    cout << print();
 }
}
```

Comment: `print()` does not return anything, so it cannot be used in such a fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` returns a `void`, so you can't use it in a `... << print()` expression. Make `print()` take the desired output stream as a parameter instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "Lab.h"
using namespace std;

void print(ostream &out = cout);

int main() {
  print();
  printToTextFile();
}

void print(ostream &out) {
  out << "Cheers";
}

void printToTextFile() {
  ofstream outfile("World.txt");
  if (outfile) {
    print(outfile);
 }
}
```